# How would I remove a section of code with the click of a button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Here is the code.

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
```

After clicking my botton I would want the code to remove the first data set. (I'd like to be able to bring it back with another click however)

So I want it to become this when the button is clicked:

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift()` to remove the first item from an array. Something like this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    data.datasets.shift();
});
```

Comment: You can remove the first item from an array in PHP, yes - however I don't see how this applies to an array you have in Javascript. If you're asking can you amend the JS array itself by using PHP, then no you can't.